# Multiple problems installing TeX Live 2021 on Windows 10

Tags: windows, tex-live

I have a Windows 10 laptop where no TeX distribution was ever installed before (double-checked for config directories, files, and environment variables).

Wanting to install TeX Live 2021, I followed the [full installation guide](http://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#installation) and also read the [Windows-specific warnings](http://tug.org/texlive/windows.html). I've now tried several times, following different installation procedures - cleaning up everything (deleting base & user directories, environment variables, etc) before each time - but still don't manage to get a working installation. Before I report a bug at tex-live@tug, I wanted to ask for advice here, in case I'm doing something wrong. Here is what I did, step by step, and the problems I encountered in the process.

**1.** First I tried running the recommended online installer [install-tl-windows.exe](https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-windows.exe). It never got past the screen that tries to contact or load from a repository, even after a 30-min wait. Tried a dozen times, choosing different mirrors nearby and far away. No luck.

**2.** Then I downloaded and unpacked the [install-tl.zip](https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl.zip) and run `install-tl-windows.bat` therein. This time the [main installation window](http://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-common/basic-w32.png) appeared. I left all default paths and environment variables (note that I *do* have write access to `C:`); in the selection scheme I unselected all languages except US & UK English, unselected XeTeX, LuaTeX, ConTeXt; also unselected TeXworks (I use Emacs), and clicked Install. After one to three hours (depending on the mirror I chose), the installation was complete.

I tried compiling a minimal latex document (see below), and got an error similar to the one in [this old question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64894/97039):

```
I can't find the format file `pdflatex.fmt'
```

Following the advice in the answers to that question and similar questions elsewhere online [such as this](https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/ppg32a/error_i_cant_find_the_format_file_pdflatexfmt/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), I tried running `texhash` and `fmtutil-sys --all`. The latter gave the error

```
no appropriate script or programme found fmtutil.
```

for which there are also many posts online.

**2a.** Not understanding what the problem could be, I re-tried with all possible combinations of the following three options: (a) choosing different mirrors; (b) leaving the full selection of packages (ie without unselecting some languages, LuaTeX etc); (c) redoing the procedure by choosing "Run as Administrator". No luck.

**3.** At this point I tried downloading the [ISO file](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html) with the full installation. Mounted the image and run `install-tl-windows.bat` (as normal user, as recommended; I repeat that I do have write access to `C:`). Everything proceeded as in step **2.** above. At the end of the installation I tried running `pdflatex` on the minimal latex document. New error this time:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./minimal-template.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>

! LaTeX Error: File `article.cls' not found.
```

Very strange. A file search revealed that `article.cls` is in the TeXLive file system; but `kpathsea` did not see it indeed.

**4.** At this point I opened the TeX Live Shell from the Start Menu; selected a CTAN mirror; updated the `TL Manager` which was not up to date; updated all packages; run `Regenerate filename database`; and run `Regenerate formats`. With the latter I got this error:

```
tex live shell:
mtutil [INFO]: total formats: 59
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 53
C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 53:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\fmtutil.pl  --sys --all
```

Here is a snip from the full set of errors appearing in the "Other" tab (I'm replacing my user directory with asterisks for privacy; note that I do have write access to these directories):

```
start load https://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/TeX/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
finish load https://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/TeX/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
start load http://contrib.texlive.info/current
finish load http://contrib.texlive.info/current
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
running mtxrun --generate ...
done running mtxrun --generate.
running updmap-sys ...
done running updmap-sys.
regenerating fmtutil.cnf in C:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist
running fmtutil-sys --byengine luatex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\rPSb0Dpak2\WW_dJvUHgX ...

tlmgr.pl: fmtutil-sys --byengine luatex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\rPSb0Dpak2\WW_dJvUHgX failed (status 255), output:
Unknown option: status-file
Try "fmtutil --help" for more information.
C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 255:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\fmtutil.pl  --sys --byengine luatex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\rPSb0Dpak2\WW_dJvUHgX 
running fmtutil-sys --byengine luajithbtex --no-error-if-no-format --no-error-if-no-engine=luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\rPSb0Dpak2\WW_dJvUHgX ...
```

I tried to continue anyway with `Regenerate fontmaps`, and then tried again pdflatex on the minimal document. New error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
---! c:/texlive/2021/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt made by different executable version
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

**5.** I tried again steps **3.** and **4.**, but with "Run as Administrator". Same errors.

OK at this point I give up and really don't know what to do. Am I doing something wrong? For the moment I have to concur with [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/498645/97039): installation of TeX Live 2021 is an utter failure.

Here is the minimal latex file I used for testing (copy & paste):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

test

\section{Section}

test

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found, that the download is not working because the system path to "cmd.exe" is not found. Therefore: open a cmd window and add the system path prior to starting the .bat file (set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Windows\system32)